# How to batch rename files in PowerShell starting with padded first numbers

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I'm a `PowerShell` newbie so please be gentle! I'm looking to bulk rename a collection of files, then pad the first digits so that they play in order on my devices.

For example, I have a folder full of mp3s `ABCDEF_S3L1_010221_GHIJK.mp3` through `ABCDEF_S3L49_210921_GHIJK.mp3`

I'm trying to rename them as `01-lesson.mp3` through `49-lesson.mp3` where the digit **after the `L` is the prefix** but I trip up with the padding for lessons `1-9` so they play out of order, i.e. `01` then `10`, `11`, `12` etc. I've tried using variations of `.PadLeft` and `{0:D2}` but keep getting errors such as:

```
Rename-Item: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

My code works without the initial padding:

```
PS G:\Temp\MP3s> Get-ChildItem -Path *.mp3 | Rename-Item
-NewName {$_.Name -replace '(^ABCDEF_S3L)(\d{1,2})_(\d{6})_(GHIJK)', '$2-lesson'}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-match` and by doing so capture the number behind the `L` in `$matches[1]`, which can be formatted like you want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.mp3' -File | 
    # apply better filename filter and capture the number after the 'L' in $matches[1]
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^\w+_S\dL(\d+)_\d+_\w+' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { ('{0:D2}-lesson{1}' -f [int]$matches[1], $_.Extension) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheating and going to powershell 7 with the scriptblock replace.  You just have to workout where the 2nd group match is within the `$_` match object, which turns out to be `$_.groups[2].value`.  Then you can use `.padleft(2,'0')` on it.

```
# echo hi | set-content ABCDEF_S3L1_010221_GHIJK.mp3,
#   ABCDEF_S3L49_210921_GHIJK.mp3


Get-ChildItem -Path *.mp3 | 
  % { $_.Name -replace '(^ABCDEF_S3L)(\d{1,2})_(\d{6})_(GHIJK)', 
  { $a = $_ } }

.mp3
.mp3


$a

Groups   : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 25
Value    : ABCDEF_S3L49_210921_GHIJK


Get-ChildItem -Path *.mp3 | 
  rename-item -newname { 
  $_.Name -replace '(^ABCDEF_S3L)(\d{1,2})_(\d{6})_(GHIJK)', 
  { $_.groups[2].value.padleft(2,'0') + '-lesson' } } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
      "Item: C:\Users\js\foo\ABCDEF_S3L1_010221_GHIJK.mp3 
Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\01-lesson.mp3".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
      "Item: C:\Users\js\foo\ABCDEF_S3L49_210921_GHIJK.mp3 
Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\49-lesson.mp3".
```